# I am facing an issue on selenium java jenkins framework. Element working on Local maven project build but not working on Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, jenkins

And And I enter Auto Created Reseller in BA Reseller add button edit field

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression None edit reseller content lib because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'None edit reseller content lib' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.64)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'QA-IZ-01', ip: '172.16.249.52', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.18'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 113.0.5672.64, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae..., userDataDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\scop...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:57100}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 76235637857a93ecc562d941c03b2d11
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=None edit reseller content lib}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at com.binaryvibes.hells.kitchen.automation.tests.framework.selenium.operations.SeleniumOperations.setText(SeleniumOperations.java:98)
    at com.binaryvibes.hells.kitchen.automation.tests.steps.predict360.Predict360StepDefinitions.inputValue(Predict360StepDefinitions.java:87)
    at ?.And I enter Auto Created Reseller in BA Reseller add button edit field(com/binaryvibes/hells/kitchen/automation/tests/predict360/businessarea/1.BAReseller.feature:180)
```

Comment: This looks like the BDD component isn't installed on the server running the system.

Comment: Hi, Kate Paulk This element is working previously but not working now other locator is working can you please guide me how to install BDD component on Jenkins server

Answer (score 0):

While working in software qa company we can get the list of all elements present in li tag for multiple purpose.

Some example are as follow.
To get the size of all the similar elements present we have to use below method

```
public int getTotalSizeOfLiElements(){
        WebElement elementName = driver.findElement(By.LocatorStrategy("LocatorValue"));
       return count.size();
    }
```

To click all the simlar elements we can do as below

```
public void clickAllOptionInLiCheckbox() {
        WebElement elementName = driver.findElement(By.LocatorStrategy("LocatorValue"));
        for (WebElement el : elements) {
                el.click();
        }
    }
```